# What's the best way to copy an image file from another domain onto local? PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I need to periodically backup an image file (as is) from my public server onto my local dev server..

What's the best way to go about it? a simple combination of `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`? or is there some other ways to do this?

and if it's `file_get_contents()` way, how does one get the contents of an image file properly/exactly in order to simply write it via file_put_contents because i don't think a simple file read is enough. (current tests are writing blank zero byte jpgs).

regards

Comment: rsync, scp, netcat, cp.. any of the command-line functions would be easier than php. Both would need to be hooked up to a cron.

Answer (score 2):

As you already know

```
Use file_get_contents() and  file_put_contents

$url = 'http://hostname/images/wml.gif';
file_put_contents('/your_path/image.gif', file_get_contents($url));
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways you can do this (if we don't restrict ourselves to PHP)

#### Shell script triggered by a cron (on remote machine)

The script runs a `rsync` or `scp` command to copy the file over via SSH.

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa /var/www/html/image.png foo@local-dev-machine:/var/www/html
```

#### file_get_contents, like you've said (on local machine)

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the **fopen wrappers have been enabled**. See fopen() for more details [...]

```
$url = 'http://hostname/images/image.png';
file_put_contents('/var/www/html/image.png', file_get_contents($url));
```

#### cURL, with PHP (on local machine)

```
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$raw=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if(file_exists($saveto)){
    unlink($saveto);
}
$fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
fwrite($fp, $raw);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to use `file_get_contents` to copy big files, as it loads the entire file to memory and could cause a crash if memory is short.

A better solution is to read it by chunks:

```
function getUrlFile($url, $path)
    {
        $newfilename = $path;
        $file = fopen($url, "rb");
        if ($file) {
            $newfile = fopen($newfilename, "wb");
            if ($newfile)
                while (!feof($file)) {
                    fwrite($newfile, fread($file, 1024 * 8), 1024 * 8);
                }
        }
        if ($file) {
            fclose($file);
        }
        if ($newfile) {
            fclose($newfile);
        }
    }
```